# Imagick PHP 5.5 extension does not work with paths. (windows)

Tags: php, windows, wamp, imagick

I'm trying to install imagick PHP extension on windows. I have problems with PHP 5.5.

Imagick version: ImageMagick-6.9.3-8-Q16-x64-dll. Module is working. I can see imagick in phpinfo().

The problem is, that imagick does not recognize path to files. For example, if I have simple index.php and a.jpg in the same folder, I can't use $im = new imagick('a.pdf'); because I get exception:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to open image `C:/wamp/www/convert_pdf_to_jpeg/image.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2702' in C:\wamp\www\convert_pdf_to_jpeg\index.php on line 7
ImagickException: unable to open image`C:/wamp/www/convert_pdf_to_jpeg/image.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2702 in C:\wamp\www\convert_pdf_to_jpeg\index.php on line 7

Comment: So is the file called `a.jpg`, `a.pdf` or `image.jpg`?

Comment: Imagick doesn't work with relative paths. Use realpath("someFile.jpg") to get the absolute filename, or false if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: I am uploading pdf file.